# Handling html code in JSON

Tags: javascript, ajax, json

I am writing code that will use AJAX requests to get some HTML code from the server to embed, but I cannot seem to get the JSON format correct. Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong?

```
{"response": 
 [
  {"code": "<div id=\”sponsors\” class=\”infoBox\” > <div class=\”title\”>THANK YOU 2011 SPONSORS!</div> <div class=\”section\”> <div class=\”party\”><a href=\”http://www.ChickRussell.com\”>Chick Russell Communications</a></div> <div class=\”cityState\”>Pasadena, California</div> <div class=\”description\”> Chick Russell Communications is a story-driven creative development company, not a design-driven company. It's one of our main distinguishing features. It doesn't matter how great it looks if it doesn't create the desired effect. <a href=\”/vendors/info/17280\”>more...</a> </div> <div class=\”web\”><a href=\”http://www.ChickRussell.com\”>www.ChickRussell.com</a></div> </div>  </div>"
  }
 ]
}
```

When I try to run `JSON.parse()` on it, I get a syntax error

Here is the code I am using to read the JSON:

```
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
var newxhr = new XMLHttpRequest()

newxhr.onreadystatechange = getResponse

function getResponse(){
    if(newxhr.readyState == 4) {
        var response = newxhr.responseText;

        console.log(response)

        response = JSON.parse(response)

        newxhr.close;
    }
}

var url = "http://*.*.net/test.json";

newxhr.open("GET", url, true);
newxhr.send(null)
</script>
```

Comment: that looks like valid json to me. Post the related code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`”` and `"` are different characters. You need **stright** quotes, not curly ones. (Tell your browser to zoom in if you can't see the difference … and don't use an editor (e.g. many word processors) that converts to curly quotes automatically, use a proper text editor (I'm fond of ActiveState Komodo)).

---

Old answer (before the JSON in the question was revised):

The first thing you are probably doing wrong, is trying to build JSON by hand. Use a library instead.

The second thing you are doing wrong is HTML encoding (badly) your quote marks. To escape a `"` inside a JSON string you represent it as `\"`.

The third thing (but it could be just that you are giving a poor example) is bothering to use an array for a single object.

> When I try to run JSON.parse() on it, I get a syntax error

Despite the problems with it, what you have is [valid JSON](http://jsonlint.com/), so that should not happen. You appear to have reduced your test case so far that the problem you are having doesn't appear in it.

Comment: I just added my JavaScript code and fixed the encoding. Is there anything wrong there?

Comment: Updated answer in response to the new JSON

Answer (score 1):

It's the double quotes. You used ” (Unicode: U+8221) instead of " (Unicode: U+34). Although they look very similar, they are two different chars.

The code below is valid:

```
{
"response": [
    {
        "code": "<div id=\"sponsors\" class=\"infoBox\" > <div class=\"title\">THANK YOU 2011 SPONSORS!</div> <div class=\"section\"> <div class=\"party\"><a href=\"http://www.ChickRussell.com\">Chick Russell Communications</a></div> <div class=\"cityState\">Pasadena, California</div> <div class=\"description\"> Chick Russell Communications is a story-driven creative development company, not a design-driven company. It's one of our main distinguishing features. It doesn't matter how great it looks if it doesn't create the desired effect. <a href=\"/vendors/info/17280\">more...</a> </div> <div class=\"web\"><a href=\"http://www.ChickRussell.com\">www.ChickRussell.com</a></div> </div>  </div>"
    }
]
}
```

You can always check your JSON code with http://jsonlint.com/ - it's a great tool.

Answer (score 0):

it seems to work for me: http://jsfiddle.net/6PV4M/1/

however, i did escape the single quotes.

```
var str = '{"response":[{"code": "<div id=\”sponsors\” class=\”infoBox\” > <div class=\”title\”>THANK YOU 2011 SPONSORS!</div> <div class=\”section\”> <div class=\”party\”><a href=\”http://www.ChickRussell.com\”>Chick Russell Communications</a></div> <div class=\”cityState\”>Pasadena, California</div> <div class=\”description\”> Chick Russell Communications is a story-driven creative development company, not a design-driven company. It\'s one of our main distinguishing features. It doesn\'t matter how great it looks if it doesn\'t create the desired effect. <a href=\”/vendors/info/17280\”>more...</a> </div> <div class=\”web\”><a href=\”http://www.ChickRussell.com\”>www.ChickRussell.com</a></div> </div>  </div>"} ]}';

var obj = JSON.decode(str);
alert(obj["response"][0]["code"]);
```

Comment: post the ajax response data from the network tab in the chrome console.

Comment: also, JSON.decode isn't really supported that well. You should either use eval , json2, or jquery.